# How can I search for specific text in a repository using the bitbucket API?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am trying to look for specific text in a repo but how can I achieve this with bitbucket server using the bitbucket version 1 API?

I am a bit limited with the advanced search feature on the bitbucket UI.

I am currently using bitbucket server version 7.21.5

Comment: what is limiting you on the JQL advanced search?  You can write some pretty complex searches with it.  Share an example of what you are trying to do

Comment: @JeremyFiel so for example if I am looking for the word "string" and "int" across multiple repos (within the UI) how can I filter my search to only return one instance of the result? I.e if "test repo" has multiple files that have "string" or "int" is it possible to only show the first result?. My main reason for this is because I need to run a string search on 20+ repos which will have many results, so I'm just wondering if there's an easier way this can be done via code